# PCI Express x16 Video card memory issue

Tags: pci-express

Can a PCI Express x16 video card that uses DDR2 OR DDR3 memory work on a computer running DDR memory? I bought a refurbished ASUS A8N5X nForce4 Motherboard & AMD64 3000+ Processor. The motherboard supports only DDR memory modules and I bought a PCI Express x16 video card that uses DDR2 memory. Will it still work on my motherboard?

Comment: I have poor luck with refurb vid cards, there is a serious reason they did not work in the first place, refurb printers I have had good luck with, less complicated. On board vid memory has nothing to do with motherboard memory slot support...

Comment: The memory on the video card has nothing to do with system RAM.  Also, generally its GDDR2, 3, 4, or 5 slightly different than ddr.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work.

The RAM on the video card is completely separate and apart from the system RAM.

Comment: His motherboard can, the Asus A8N5X. It has 4 DDR 400 memory slots, an x16 PCIe slot, an x4, PCIe slot, two x1 PCIe slots, and 3 PCI slots.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: Also, PCI-E versions are compatible so a PCI-E 2.0 card will work on PCI-E 1.1 slot, as example.

Comment: @Overmind - Right, which is why I didn't make any mention of compatibility.

Comment: Yes, but it's usually the next related thing most-asked.